# How to override mongoid client in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to override my client connection and database when I come to save some files using GridFs.

I've found the `Mongoid.override_client` method, however I'm unsure how to use this.

I've added a new client into the mongoid.yml file below the default db:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      #standard default db stuff
    attachDb:
      database: attachments
      hosts: 
          - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary_preferred
        truncate_logs: false
        user: username
        password: password
        auth_mech: :scram
        auth_source: authDb
```

When I run the following

```
Mongoid::Clients.clients.each do |name, client|
   puts name
   puts client
end
```

It only shows my default database

I've also tried running `Mongoid.override_client(:attachDb)` just in case it worked but it doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I get my new client connection working?

Comment: Have you seen this section? https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#runtime-persistence-options

Comment: @OlegP I had not seen that, however I'm not saving a model. I'm purely wanting to change the client when I come to saving a file with GridFs, like this:

`attFile = File.open(@tmpFile.path)
grid_fs = Mongoid::GridFS
grid_file = grid_fs.put(attFile.path)`

Comment: Mongoid source code does not contain the string "GridFS". I don't know what "Mongoid::GridFS" is but it is not part of the official Mongoid project.

Comment: Yeah I'm using a Gem to allow me to use GridFs, however that doesn't really matter at the moment.

I just need to know if there's a way to change what Mongoid client I'm using on the fly, without specifying it in the save method.

Comment: The linked documentation shows how to change the client used for an operation. What are you attempting to do that the documentation does not cover?

Answer (score 0):

When you call Mongoid.override_client(:attachDb), all query and command to database will connect to the client you have overridden in this thread.
Like:

```
User.where.first() # return first User in default db.
Mongoid.override_client(:attachDb)
User.where.first() # return first User in attachDb db.
```

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply.

This isn't working for me - When I run Mongoid::Config.clients I only get my default database. Can you see anything wrong with my mongoid.yml?

Comment: I see you connect replicaSet `mode: :primary_preferred` while localhost. Could you remove options read mode and try again.